# minizinc sitting friends at a table, sharing common interests

Tags: set, compare, minizinc

this is my model... trying to put friends one next to other at N=16 POTITIONS of a cyclic table. friends have interests. one next to each other **MUST HAVE AT LEAST ONE COMMON INTEREST**.

```
 int :N;
    set of int: FRIENDS  = 1..N;
    set of int: POSITIONS = 1..N;
    array[FRIENDS] of set of int: interests;
    array[POSITIONS] of var FRIENDS : friends_at;
    include "alldifferent.mzn";
    constraint alldifferent(friend_at);

    constraint forall(i in 2..N-1)(
   (interests[friend_at[i+1]]<=interests[friend_at[i]]  \/ interests[friend_at[i+1]]>=interests[friend_at[i]])
/\ 
( interests[friend_at[i-1]]<=interests[friend_at[i]]  \/ interests[friend_at[i-1]]>=interests[friend_at[i]])
/\ 
( interests[friend_at[N]]<=interests[friend_at[1]]    \/ interests[friend_at[N]]>=interests[friend_at[1]])
);

    solve satisfy;
```

N=16
The array of their interests:

```
interests=[{1},{2,3},{3,2},{2},{2,3},{2,1},{1,3},{3},{2,1},{3,1},{1,2},{2},{2,3},{2,3},{3},{2}];
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Also, this model is not complete. It lacks the declration of `interests`. Would you please add the "interests" matrix as well, it makes it easier to understand your model.

Comment: interests= [{2,1,3},{2,1,3},{3,2},{3,2,1},{2,1,3},{2,3,1},{1,2,3},{3,1},{2,3,1},{3,2,1},{1,3,2},{3,1,2},{2,3},{1,2},{2,3,1},{2,3}];

my error:

C:/Users/�������/Documents/������/����������/Gala/gala.mzn:36:
MiniZinc: flattening error: 'set_le' is used in a reified context but no reified version is available

Comment: in previous comment... there are common differents in all sets... excuse me for that..
interests=
[  {1},
  {2,3},
  {3,2},
  {2},
  {2,3},
  {2,1},
  {1,3},
  {3},
  {2,1},
  {3,1},
  {1,2},
  {2},
  {2,3},
  {2,3},
  {3},
  {2}
  ];

Comment: Friend no1 can't be left or right to Friend no2 as they have different interests.

Friend 1 could be next to Friend 6... they have common interest the {1}.

I should find a way to compare their interests and put friends next to eachother if they have common interests.. (at least one)

Comment: The model as it stand does not work since it lacks a couple of arrays and definitions, "friends_at", interests", and "FRIENDS". Would you mind update your question with the complete model?

Comment: of course.. i've just upfated my question.
my problem is that i don't know how to implement the constraint in bolds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a model that seems to work. The main approach is to use the set operation `intersect` to ensure that two neighbours have at least one common interest.

```
int :N;
set of int: FRIENDS  = 1..N;
set of int: POSITIONS = 1..N;
array[FRIENDS] of set of int: interests;
array[POSITIONS] of var FRIENDS : friend_at;
include "alldifferent.mzn";

constraint alldifferent(friend_at);

constraint 
   forall(i in 2..N-1) (
      card(interests[friend_at[i+1]] intersect interests[friend_at[i]]) > 0 
   )
   /\ 
   card(interests[friend_at[N]] intersect interests[friend_at[1]]) > 0;
```

solve satisfy;

N=16;
   interests=[{1},{2,3},{3,2},{2},{2,3},{2,1},{1,3},{3},{2,1},{3,1},{1,2},{2},{2,3},{2,3},{3},{2}];

output [ "friend_at:(friend_at)\n"] ++
   [
     "p:(p) interests:(interests[friend_at[p]])\n"
     | p in POSITIONS
   ];

There are many solutions, here's the first one:

```
 friend_at:[7, 15, 14, 16, 13, 12, 11, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 1]
 p:1 interests:{1,3}
 p:2 interests:3..3
 p:3 interests:2..3
 p:4 interests:2..2
 p:5 interests:2..3
 p:6 interests:2..2
 p:7 interests:1..2
 p:8 interests:1..2
 p:9 interests:{1,3}
 p:10 interests:3..3
 p:11 interests:2..3
 p:12 interests:2..2
 p:13 interests:2..3
 p:14 interests:2..3
 p:15 interests:1..2
 p:16 interests:1..1
```

Here one can check that all neighbours (including the first and last) has at least one common interest.